# Copy Clipboard using zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I've a requirement where I need to copy text to `Clipboard`.
So, I've gone through some samples and started using `zeroclipboard`.

Now, my problem is :
The demo which is shown on the home page of http://zeroclipboard.org/
is only working when we are `manually clicking` the button.
But if we `trigger a click` event for the button, the text is `not getting copied` to the clipboard.

Is this possible to get the `text copied to Clipboard on button click event`?

Comment: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/183

Comment: Do you think the user would want you to overwrite what they have in their clipboard without them knowing about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second paragraph on the [zeroclipboard github readme doc](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard)

> **Limitations**
>
> **User Interaction Required**
>
> Due to browser and Flash security restrictions, this clipboard injection can ONLY occur when the user clicks on the invisible Flash movie. A simulated click event from JavaScript will not suffice as this would enable clipboard poisoning.

Comment: I disagree- I may have temporarily saved something important in my clipboard. I like this security feature.